# is it possible to use CNAME (alias) for <host:port>

Tags: jsp, servlets, webserver, jetty

Is there a way i can hide the port from url and use cname (alias) instead of :.

For e.g. If my url is http://myserver.com:40089/webapps/index.jsp
Is its possible for me to use
http://mycname/webapps/index.jsp

Reason i am telling is, i can move around the box called myserver.com to say myserver1.com. I dont want client to always change this url whenever i am moving. Instead my client should be unaware of where the service is running and on which  port.

Is it possible? I am using jetty as my webserver.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can't set port. What's problem with standard 80 port?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please see this similar question that has been asked there: [Can DNS point to specific port?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55123/can-dns-point-to-specific-port)

Answer (score 14):

With DNS CNAME you can only point from one hostname to another. Port numbers are a totally different piece of cake.

There are several problems with the described situation:

- if you set the CNAME in your DNS you probably have to modify your webserver as well to handle the new hostname because HTTP protocol works like this
- as @stevevis said you'll loose your cookies and caches and even the rankings in the search engines
- you still have to include the port number in your addresses: `http://mycname:40080/webapps/index.jsp`

You haven't mentioned but I assume that you cannot modify your webserver settings, because in this case you could modify the port number as well.

But there is a solution for this problem with small sacrifices.

You can install an HTTP reverse proxy server to forward the requests to the webserver (for e.g. [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/), [nginx](http://nginx.org/), etc.) but with this you'll loose the original clients' IP address (of course you can forward it in an HTTP header but you have to modify the code on your previous domain to handle this).

Answer (score 4):

No. CNAME only maps names, not ports. You need a reverse proxy if you want to map x:b to c:d.

Answer (score 4):

Try using a SRV record for doing that. It is what I used to get a custom domain for my minecraft server.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

yes and no...  yes you can use the cname interchangeably (though keep in mind that cookies may not go along for the ride depending on their domain), but if your server is running on a port other than 80, you'll have to include the port number in the URL.

Comment: how can i do that? I am not using cookie. Its just used to expose webservice and show simple webpage.

Comment: all you have to do is ensure that links output by your application (and shared by you) point to mycname.  if you want to be more slick, you can use apache and mod_rewrite to redirect all traffic destined for myserver.com -> mycname.