# How to set up DNS for multiple web apps on the same server?

Tags: apache, tomcat, dns

I have a scenario as follows:

I have one Windows 2003 server that has 2 web servers running on it, one is Tomcat(port 80), the other one is Domino(port 8080). Basically I would like to set up 2 server names such as: tomcat.mydomain.com and domino.mydomain.com, so that tomcat.mydomain.com goes to the tomcat web app at url of www.mydomain.com/tomcat_app_name, and dominio.mydomain.com goes to www.mydomain.com:8080/domino_app_name.

How could I achieve this? Do I need to set up an Apache Web server?

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add CNAME records for tomcat and domino.

```
tomcat CNAME    www.mydomain.com.
domino CNAME    www.mydomain.com.
```

This is enough if you have each server on different TCP ports.

Comment: I just got some other tips from
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604688/is-it-possible-to-use-cname-alias-for-hostport