# Sparkjava. How to run my site on my own domain name?

Tags: apache, webserver, spark-java

I can run Spark on necessary port on localhost, but I can't find info how to run my site on my own domain name (not localhost).

Should I also run and configure any webserver, such as Apache Httpd?

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2, JRE 8.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to follow the instructions from your host provider. For example, I have an app hosted at OpenShift. Openshift recomends the use of CNAME records, I just followed their instructions, and [my app](http://cheff.casa) is on air.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't do like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604688/is-it-possible-to-use-cname-alias-for-hostport

Comment: What is your host provider? Do you have a static IP?

Comment: Yes, I have static IP on the server. But I'm going to use it for more then 1 site.

Comment: I used to deploy a single SparkJava site per server. According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015138/how-to-redirect-dns-to-different-ports) there is a way to set a DNS record to point to a specific port number, but this isn't right up my alley.